# Hook WH_GETMESSAGE message

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm trying to hook `WH_GETMESSAGE` from my class to determine the moment when specific window is resizing. However, looks like the hook isn't set.

Class from where I try to hook:

```
class WindowDisplayHelper : // public ...
{    
public:
    // some other public methods here
    void SetMsgHook();
protected:
    LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProcHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    static LRESULT CALLBACK MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
private:
    // some other private members there
    HWND m_windowHandle;
    bool m_isWindowResizing = false;
    static HHOOK m_msgHook;
    static WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow* m_pThis;
};
```

.cpp file:

```
WindowDisplayHelper* WindowDisplayHelper ::m_pThis = nullptr;
HHOOK WindowDisplayHelper ::m_msgHook = NULL;

void WindowDisplayHelper ::SetMsgHook()
{
    m_pThis = this;
    m_msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgPoc, NULL, 0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowDisplayHelper::MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (m_pThis != nullptr)
    {
        return m_pThis->GetMsgProcHook(code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowDisplayHelper::GetMsgProcHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DUMPER_INFO("Hooked");
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    MSG* lpmsg = (MSG*)lParam;
    DUMPER_INFO("Hooked for HWND: %p. Current window %p", lpmsg->hwnd, m_windowHandle);
    if (lpmsg->hwnd != m_windowHandle)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (lpmsg->message == WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE && !m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        DUMPER_INFO("Start window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = true;
    }
    else if (lpmsg->message == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE && m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        DUMPER_INFO("Stop window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = false;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Here is how I create WindowDisplayHelper object:

```
bool DisplayManager::CreateWindowDisplay(TDisplayId displayId, void * windowHandle)
{
    auto helper = boost::make_shared<WindowDisplayHelper>(windowHandle);
    helper->SetMsgHook();
    AddDisplayHelper(displayId, helper);

    return true;
}
```

Though I call SetMsgHook() after the object is created, looks like hook isn't set, because I don't see any debug outputs in my log file and `m_isWindowResizing` variable always == false. So the question is why my hook doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the threadId on the `SetWindowsHookEx` call

Comment: Also it seems like the hook procedure will always forward to the last window set it up for.. (m_pThis) - is that intentional ?

Comment: `m_pThis` is used because I can't use non-static functions as a `SetWindowsHookEx` parameter, so I use static function with static pointer.  As it seen from `SetWindowsHookEx` documentation, the function should work with ThreadId = 0, but I'll try to set ThreadId by calling `GetCurrentThreadId`

Comment: Using `GetCurrentThreadId` didn't help

Comment: @rudolfninja "*I can't use non-static functions as a `SetWindowsHookEx` parameter*" - you can if you use a thunk for the callback. But that is an advanced technique that most coders don't know how to use. "*the function should work with ThreadId = 0*" - that requires the hook code to reside in a DLL that is then injected into other processes, as the hook callback is run in the context of each thread that retrieves window messages. Which means you need separate DLLs for hooking 32bit and 64bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgPoc, NULL, 0);
```

This line produce a ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD (1428) [system error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-). It means that Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle. If you set `dwThreadId` parameter to zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread. It is a nonload hook you need specified a valid `hmod` parameter. You need put the hook code in a DLL as @Remy Lebeau pointed out.

Or set a valid `dwThreadId` parameter using GetCurrentThreadId() as @rudolfninja pointed out.

I test based on a Windows Desktop Application Template with the following code. It works. You can have a try.

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    // ...

    HHOOK m_msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgPoc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Hooked");
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    MSG* lpmsg = (MSG*)lParam;
    //OutputDebugString("Hooked for HWND: %p. Current window %p", lpmsg->hwnd, m_windowHandle);
    if (lpmsg->hwnd != m_windowHandle)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (lpmsg->message == WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE && !m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Start window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = true;
    }
    else if (lpmsg->message == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE && m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Stop window resizing");
        m_isWindowResizing = false;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in your example non-class member function is used (as a `lpfn` parameter). But I need to modify and check class members (m_isWindowResizing and m_windowHandle) inside of HOOKPROC. So if I  use `GetCurrentThreadId()` to set `dwThreadId` and make HOOKPROC non-class member, is it possible to pass somehow `this` pointer to the HOOKPROC in order to modify class object?

Comment: @rudolfninja Your hook doesn't work because you don't register it successfully as I pointed out in my answer. As for how to modify class object this is a C++ programming problem you can open an new question to focus this.